# moment.utc() is using DST offset

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Not sure why this is happening but I'm changing my computer's local time for testing and when I moment.utc() compared between two different dates (March 8th and March 15th) there's a different of exactly one hour. Not sure why this is happening as I thought UTC didn't observe DST.

This is the code I'm using the generate the moment and view the time.

`const now = moment.utc().format("h:mm A z")`

Comment: Hi.  As you said, UTC doesn't change for DST - thus the problem is likely elsewhere. 
 You'll need to edit your question to provide code that demonstrates the issue.  Please read [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help center.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're changing the local date but not the local time, then the UTC time will appear to have changed because you've effectively changed your local offset by going over the DST boundary. E.g. 08:00 local will be a different UTC time for the two dates not because UTC has changed, but because local time has changed.